# How to decode binary audio data?

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm still new to web development and I'm making a chatbot, but I want to run the responses through googles text to speech first and then play the sound on the client. So client sends message to server -> server creates a response -> server sends message to google -> gets audio data back -> sends it to client -> client plays it. I got all the way to the last step but now I'm out of my depth.

I've been doing some googling and there seems to be a lot of info on playing audio from binary data, audio contexts and so on and I've created a function but it doesn't work. Here's what I've done:

```
export const SendMessage: Client.Common.Footer.API.SendMessage = async message => {
    const baseRoute = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_ROUTE;
    const port = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_PORT;
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    let audio: any;
    const url = baseRoute + ":" + port + "/ChatBot";
    console.log("%c Sending post request...", "background: #1fa67f; color: white", url, JSON.stringify(message));
    let responseJson = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(message)
    });
    let response = await responseJson.json();
    await audioContext.decodeAudioData(
        new ArrayBuffer(response.data.audio.data),
        buffer => {
            audio = buffer;
        },
        error => console.log("===ERROR===\n", error)
    );
    const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audio;
    source.connect(audioContext.destination);
    source.start(0);
    console.log("%c Post response:", "background: #1fa67f; color: white", url, response);
};
```

This function sends sends the message to the server and gets back the response message and audio data. I do have some sort of binary data in my response.data.audio.data but I'm getting an error saying that audio data can't be decoded (the error in the decodeAudioData method is firing). I know the data is valid because, on my server, I use the following code to turn it into an mp3 file which plays fine:

```
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
await writeFile("output/TTS.mp3", response.audioContent, "binary");
```

I have almost no knowledge of how binary data is handled here and what could be going wrong. Do I need to specify further parameters to decode the binary data correctly? How do I know which? I would like to understand what's actually happening here and not just copy paste some solution.

EDIT:

So it seems the array buffer isn't being created properly. If I run this code:

```
    console.log(response);
    const audioBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(response.data.audio.data);
    console.log("===audioBuffer===", audioBuffer);
    audio = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioBuffer);
```

The response  comes out as:

```
{message: "Message successfully sent.", status: 1, data: {…}}
    message: "Message successfully sent."
    status: 1
    data:
        message: "Sorry, I didn't understand your question, try rephrasing."
        audio:
            type: "Buffer"
            data: Array(14304)
                [0 … 9999]
                [10000 … 14303]
                length: 14304
            __proto__: Array(0)
        __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

but the buffer logs as this:

```
===audioBuffer=== 
ArrayBuffer(0) {}
    [[Int8Array]]: Int8Array []
    [[Uint8Array]]: Uint8Array []
    [[Int16Array]]: Int16Array []
    [[Int32Array]]: Int32Array []
    byteLength: 0
__proto__: ArrayBuffer
```

Clearly JS doesn't understand the format in  my response object, but that's what I got from google's text to speech API. Maybe I'm sending it wrong from my server? Like I said before, on  my server the following code turns that array into a mp3  file:

```
    const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
    await writeFile("output/TTS.mp3", response.audioContent, "binary");
    return response.audioContent;
```

Where response.audioContent is also sent to the client like so:

```
//in index.ts
...
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.post("/TextToSpeech", TextToSpeechController);
...
//textToSpeech.ts
export const TextToSpeechController = async (req: Req<Server.API.TextToSpeech.RequestQuery>, res: Response) => {
    let response: Server.API.TextToSpeech.ResponseBody = {
        message: null,
        status: CONSTANTS.STATUS.ERROR,
        data: undefined
    };
    try {
        console.log("===req.body===", req.body);
        if (!req.body) throw new Error("No message recieved");
        const audio = await TextToSpeech({ message: req.body.message });
        response = {
            message: "Audio file successfully created!",
            status: CONSTANTS.STATUS.SUCCESS,
            data: audio
        };
        res.send(response);
    } catch (error) {
        response = {
            message: "Error converting text to speech: " + error.message,
            status: CONSTANTS.STATUS.ERROR,
            data: undefined
        };
        res.json(response);
    }
};
...
```

I find it weird  that, on my server, response.audioContent logs as:

```
===response.audioContent=== <Buffer ff f3 44 c4 00 00 00 03 48 01 40 00 00 f0 
a3 0f fc 1a 00 11 e1 48 7f e0 e0 87 fc b8 88 40 1c 7f e0 4c 03 c1 d9 ef ff ec 
3e 4c 02 c7 88 7f ff f9 ff ff ... >
```

But, on the client, it's

```
audio:
            type: "Buffer"
            data: Array(14304)
                [0 … 9999]
                [10000 … 14303]
                length: 14304
            __proto__: Array(0)
        __proto__: Object
```

I tried  passing response.data, response.data.audio and response.data.audio.data to new ArrayBuffer() but all result in the same empty buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things in your code, you can't populate the `ArrayBuffer` via that constructor function. Your call to `decodeAudioData` is async and will cause `audio` to be `undefined`. I would recommend that you update the call to `decodeAudioData` to the newer promised based function.

**EDIT:**
You must be doing something strange with your call to Google Text to Speech and the returned result for the previous example that I posted not to work, because whether I use an mp3 or the response from Google, they both work, once passed the correct reference of the `buffer`.

The fact you can get it to work with the `mp3` file and not the text to speech may be that you are not referencing the correct property in the result returned from the call to google's api. The response from the api call is an `Array` so make sure that you are referencing the `0` index in the result array (see `textToSpeech.js` below).

Full application described below.

```
// textToSpeech.js
const textToSpeech = require('@google-cloud/text-to-speech');
const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();

module.exports = {
    say: async function(text) {
        const request = {
            input: { text },
            voice: { languageCode: 'en-US', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL' },
            audioConfig: { audioEncoding: 'MP3' },
          };
        const response = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
        return response[0].audioContent    
    }
}
```

```
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const textToSpeechService = require('./textToSpeech');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.get('/speech', async (req, res) => {
    const buffer = await textToSpeechService.say('hello world');
    res.json({
        status: `y'all good :)`,
        data: buffer
    })
});

app.listen(3000);
```

```
// index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script>
        async function play() {
            const audioContext = new AudioContext();
            const request = await fetch('/speech');
            const response = await request.json();
            const arr = Uint8Array.from(response.data.data)
            const audio = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arr.buffer);
            const source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
            source.buffer = audio;
            source.connect(audioContext.destination);
            source.start(0);
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello Audio</h1>
        <button onclick="play()">play</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this out as soon as I'm able.

Comment: updated answer, as there is no need to convert to hex.

Comment: I was converting the array buffer improperly, like you said, but that wasn't the problem. It seems like whatever the problem is, it's a problem with encoding type. Your example shows how to convert an mp3 file to a buffer and send it to the client, and I can make that work, I can even use the data from the google API to create an mp3, then create a buffer form the mp3 file and send that to the client. This works but is a silly solution using up memory and processing power to create a pointless file. I *should* be able to send the data directly to the client and use it there but no clue how...

Comment: Have updated my answer with a working example with call to Google's text to speech API

Comment: I finally made it work, it didn't work even with your example but it gave me enough to work off that I found where I made the mistake. It was a typo I made in the server code that screwed up the conversion. Thanks a lot for your help, would never have found this if I didn't have some counterexample to work off of.

Comment: Hi, I have a very similar issue: mp3 produced by the google speech api can't be played by google chrome and I get an error "Unable to decode audio data". How did you fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
const audioBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(response.data.audio.data);
console.log("===audioBuffer===", audioBuffer);
```

maybe try

```
const audioBuffer = Buffer.from(response.data.audio);
console.log("===audioBuffer===", audioBuffer);
```